# can't press space bar with down arrow key at the same time *anymore*

Tags: keyboard

I play some games that allow me to press <kbd>Space Bar</kbd> to increase game speed, everything used to work perfectly fine but all of a sudden one day <kbd>Space Bar</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> no longer works. More specifically, now only one works but not both at the same time, I can hold space then <kbd>Up rrow</kbd> to move up quickly in my game but releasing <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd>" and pressing <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> gives no reaction on my screen. On the other hand, hold <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> then <kbd>Space Bar</kbd> would do nothing.
Yes, only one of the 2 keys works at a time, but they **used to** work together!
Is this what's called "keyboard jamming" or "ghosting" as I have read on the internet?
I'd really really appreciate some help. Again, they *used to* work together perfectly before I downloaded and played some new games found online.
I have tried switching USB ports, no help. Keyboard is a DELL Keyboard which used to have no issue whatsoever before this issue comes up.

**Edit:**
I haven't tried another keyboard at this time, do you think a new keyboard would help?

Comment: Have you tried with a different keyboard or is it just with the Dell keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

To be fair this is happening to me right now, i try to press space bar and w and this also happens with shift for me. All i did was take apart my keyboard and give it a clean